# cmake to make multiple executable files

Tags: c++, cmake

Currently, I have CMakeLists and hoge.cpp in a directory, and running CMakeLists and make command generates hoge executable file.

Now I added hoge2.cpp and want to be able to generate two different hoge and hoge2 executable files by running CMakeLists and "make hoge" and "make hoge2" commands.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html

Comment: Show your code (with single executable). Then we can suggest how to transform it for your new requirements. However, as stated above, it is sufficient to add another `add_executable` call with appropriate parameters. And this is that basis, which you should understand from any tutorial...

Answer (score 6):

Create two build targets in your CMakeLists.txt file.

```
add_executable( hoge hoge.cpp )
add_executable( hoge2 hoge2.cpp )
```

Then you can run (from same directory as your CMakeLists.txt file,

```
cmake --build . --target hoge
```

For the other build target use

```
cmake --build . --target hoge2
```

You can refer to the CMake documentation or the man pages for more information. Try running CMake with just the `--build` flag to get help.