# How to run gtest?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm new to using gtest (actually, C++ in general)
I'm making an application where I need to have unit tests (using CLion IDE, in case if that matters).

The steps I followed:

1. Download gtest from [GitHub](https://github.com/google/googletest).
2. Extracted the zip file into a new `lib` directory in my project.
3. Modify CMakeLists.txt

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
   project(my_project)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

   add_subdirectory(lib/gtest) # I renamed googletest-master folder to gtest, so that should be fine.
   include_directories(lib/gtest/googletest/include)
   include_directories(lib/gtest/googlemock/include)

   add_executable(my_project main.cpp blablabla1.h blablabla1.cpp blabla2.h blabla2.cpp etc...)

   target_link_libraries(my_project gtest gtest_main)
   ```
4. Created a new directory called `Tests` and added a cpp file in it with the following code:

   ```cpp
   #include "gtest/gtest.h"
   #include "gmock/gmock.h"

   TEST(TrivialTest, Negative) {
       ASSERT_EQ(0, 1);
   }
   ```
5. I'm stuck here, how should I run this test? If I put the following code in `main` function, then tests will start every time a normal run to the program is made. I want to somehow separate the normal program running, from the unit tests running.

   ```cpp
   #include "gtest/gtest.h"
   #include "gmock/gmock.h"

   int main() {
       testing::InitGoogleTest();
       return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you missunderstand the way of unit testing in C++. In C++ you can only run whole executable files and not parts of it. That's why you mostly have one executable/library for your application and one distinct executable for the unit tests.

Comment: @MikevanDyke How can the same project generate two `exe`s (one for my application and one for unit tests) ?

Comment: you can add multiple executables to the cmake file with `add_executable` like it is done in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344925/7699037). Thus, you would have something like `add_executable(testexe testmain.cpp fileA.cpp fileB.cpp testFileA.cpp testFileB.cpp)` and `add_executable(exe main.cpp fileA.cpp fileB.cpp)`. Note that you also need two different main files, one for the test executable and one for you application.

Comment: @MikevanDyke you can always run a specific number of unitest as part of an executable right? I mean using -gtest_filter="UnitTestClassName.*" where * can also be replaced with 1 specific test.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The test source files should be made an seperated executable file, it has its own main function.

Your main source code should not contain

```
    testing::InitGoogleTest();
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

This is what you want.